# Sending files between raspberry pi's over bluetooth using obexftp

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, file-transfer

I am trying to use obexftp to send a file between two raspberry Pi 3 B devices There are tutorials, that helped in sending/receiving files between a Pi and a PC/phone but I couldn't do it between two Pi s. A Sdptool browse doesn't show any ftp service running in the Pi. How can this be implemented so that a file can be sent/received?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The raspberry Pi doesn't have an obex ftp service. Hence, I ran a listener,
obexpushd in one device and used ussp-push to send the file. More details can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth#ObexFS)

Comment: The link provided in the answer does not offer the promised details on listener, obexpushd or ussp-push